# Display dynamic ranges from a database table and count the rows within each range

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have database table like this:

[image]

I want to display different 5-year age ranges and the counts of students that are in that range like below:

[image]

Here, the lowest age is 10 so we first calculate the range 10-15. There are 5 students within that range. For the second range, we need to find the age>15 which is 18. So, the second range is from 18-23, and so on. I would appreciate any help where the range is automatically calculated and count the data within that range.

Comment: There is such a function called `range()` and `count()`. Then there's `min()` and `max()`, and `BETWEEN`. All of which may be of use to you. Not to mention `<` - `=` - `>` operators.

Comment: ^ useful? If not, let me know and I will delete that comment (including this one), since it'll just take up room for nothing. If you want to add stuff, then use `sum()` and `count()` aggregate MySQL functions.

Comment: OP, I have edited my answer based on your requirements for dynamically determining the ranges. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: could you explain deeper why second range started from 18?

Comment: @Alex I believe it's because there's no students ages 16 or 17. The first range starts at 10 because 10 is the youngest student, and covers the next 5 years. Then, they seem to be looking for the youngest age of the remaining students (in other words, the youngest age that is greater than 15) which in our case is 18. The same applies to the start of the next two ranges.

Comment: :-) ok. is that your guess? sounds not very clear for me and not very structured. if next range can start +10 or +20 years why range is just 5 years? what logic is? :-)

Comment: I don't know their reasoning for it, but that seems to be the pattern they used. I thought it was weird, too. It would be much easier to implement a query that handles groups in constant intervals of 5, but I just went with what they had. @Alex

Comment: :) thank you @McAdam. your guess is correct. " it's because there's no students ages 16 or 17. The first range starts at 10 because 10 is the youngest student, and covers the next 5 years. Then, they seem to be looking for the youngest age of the remaining students (in other words, the youngest age that is greater than 15) which in our case is 18. The same applies to the start of the next two ranges. "

Comment: @SujanShrestha did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a condition inside of a SUM() statement to get a count where that condition holds. I would count the conditions where the age is BETWEEN() the necessary range. Try this:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(age BETWEEN 10 AND 15) AS '10-15',
  SUM(age BETWEEN 18 AND 23) AS '18-23',
  SUM(age BETWEEN 26 AND 31) AS '26-31',
  SUM(age BETWEEN 34 AND 39) AS '34-39'
FROM myTable;
```

This will only return one row, but it will have everything you need. Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6db00/4) example.

**EDIT** I misunderstood your question to automatically calculate the various ranges. I will leave my previous answer here because it may be beneficial to future readers looking for hard coded ranges. To do this, you'll have to set up a variable. I made a sort of running total type approach to get the groups. I started by setting @a to 0 before the query. Then, I needed to get two values:

- The minimum age from the table where age > @a
- 5 greater than that variable.

I did this by changing the value of @a as necessary:

- @a := (SELECT MIN(age) FROM myTable WHERE age >= @a)
- @a := @a + 5

Then, I included these in a `CONCAT()` block and casted these values as chars in order to get the groups that I needed. It may look complicated, so I hope I explained the concept:

```
SELECT CONCAT
   (CAST(@a := (SELECT MIN(age) FROM myTable WHERE age > @a) AS CHAR), 
   ' - ', 
   CAST((@a := @a + 5) AS CHAR)) AS ageRange
FROM myTable
WHERE @a <= (SELECT MAX(age) FROM myTable);
```

Doing this gave me four rows, each with the age ranges you expect. I had to add the where clause because otherwise I would get one result row for each row in the table, which would give us several null rows.

Last, I included a subquery to get the count of students whose age is within the necessary range. Note that the first part changes the values of @a, so instead of checking from @a to @a + 5, I check from @a-5 to @a. Here is the final query:

```
SET @a = 0;
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(@a := (SELECT MIN(age) FROM myTable WHERE age > @a) AS CHAR), ' - ', CAST((@a := @a + 5) AS CHAR)) AS ageRange,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE age BETWEEN @a - 5 AND @a) AS numStudents
FROM myTable
WHERE @a <= (SELECT MAX(age) FROM myTable)
GROUP BY ageRange;
```

It worked beautifully in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6db00/30). Completely dynamic and returns the various groups of 5 without any prior knowledge of which groups to take.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
      WHEN age>=10 AND age<=15 THEN '10-15' 
      WHEN age>=18 AND age<=23 THEN '18-23' 
      WHEN age>=26 AND age<=31 THEN '26-31' 
      WHEN age>=34 AND age<=39 THEN '34-39'
      ELSE 'OTHER'
   END
   AS age_range,
   COUNT(*) as number_of_students
FROM table
GROUP BY age_range
```

Comment: These ranges are all hardcoded, something that OP (probably) does not want. There is nothing dynamic in it.

Comment: yes... I think I'll update the answer as soon as author will clarify requirements