# Mysql group by where delta between records X

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, delta

I need help to write MySQL query.

I have table full of logs where one of the column is unix timestamp.
I want to group (GROUP BY) those records so that events that were made in close range time (i.e. 5 sec) between each of them are in one group.

For example:

Table:

```
timestamp
----------
1429016966
1429016964
1429016963
1429016960
1429016958
1429016957
1429016950
1429016949
1429016943
1429016941
1429016940
1429016938
```

Become to groups like that:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(timestamp)                                            | COUNT(*)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
1429016966,1429016964,1429016963,1429016960,1429016958,1429016957  |    6
1429016950,1429016949                                              |    2                         
1429016943,1429016941,1429016940,1429016938                        |    4
```

Of course I can work with the data array afterwards in php, but I think that mysql would do it faster.

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code writing service.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I will try to work this out, but I have given a similar answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28769211/display-dynamic-ranges-from-a-database-table-and-count-the-rows-within-each-rang/28769750#28769750) that might be helpful to you.

Comment: I know it's not. I've already searched for a couple of hours, but best I've found is group by time interval i.e. 10 min, 1 hour etc. where timestamp is divided by 600, 3600.

Comment: I don't think your groups are right, because the first group spans 9 seconds, not 5.

Comment: Well there is the problem that group must contain of items where difference between each of item cannot be bigger than i.e. 5 sec. Whole group can be 1 min, 10 min or whatever. If difference is more than 5 sec than next group should be created.

Comment: Ah, I see. I misunderstood, because I thought you wanted only items that happened within 5 seconds (i.e. 10:00:01 and 10:00:05). Now I see you want them grouped as long as the difference doesn't exceed 5 seconds.

Comment: That is exactly what I want McAdam331.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started by using a variable to get the position of each row, where 1 is the highest time column and ending with the lowest, like this:

```
SET @a := 0;

SELECT timeCol, @a := @a + 1 AS position
FROM myTable
ORDER BY timeCol DESC;
```

For simplicity, we will call this `positionsTable` so that the rest of the query will be more readable. Once I created that table, I used a 'time_group' variable that checked if a previous row was within the last 5 seconds. If it was, we keep the same time_group. It sounds ugly, and looks kind of ugly, but it's like this:

```
SELECT m.timeCol, m.position,
  CASE WHEN (SELECT p.timeCol FROM positionsTable p WHERE p.position = m.position - 1) <= m.timeCol + 5 
    THEN @time_group 
    ELSE @time_group := @time_group + 1 END AS timeGroup
FROM positionsTable m;
```

And then ultimately, using that as a subquery, you can group them:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(timeCol), COUNT(*)
FROM(
  SELECT m.timeCol, m.position,
    CASE WHEN (SELECT p.timeCol FROM positionsTable p WHERE p.position = m.position - 1) <= m.timeCol + 5 
    THEN @time_group 
    ELSE @time_group := @time_group + 1 END AS timeGroup
  FROM positionsTable m) tmp
GROUP BY timeGroup;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3330/6) example.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37d88/20

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t1.t) as `time`,
     COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT * 
        FROM  table1 
        ORDER BY t) as t1
GROUP BY CASE WHEN (@start+5)>=t THEN @start 
   ELSE @start:=t END
```